# Does SQA handle the SO-style SQA and the 'Programmers'-style SQA questions?

Tags: discussion, subjective-questions

Inspired by [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/is-my-pay-fair-just-based-on-the-fact-i-have-little-experience#question), it occurs to me that this exact problem happened to Stack Overflow: questions about algorithms and data structures were also mixed in with questions about bosses, productivity, wages, and the like. The solution in that case was to make a second site, Programmers.

How do we plan to handle this? Should we funnel these to Programmers? Or accept them under the umbrella of testing (in the same vein that Stack Overflow did early in its tenure)?

Answer (score 5):

I think we should accept them here ... we need all the traffic we can get :-)

Comment: Plus it is still in the scope of a SQA.  If we get too many (large percentage) of these questions, it might be  the time to think of forking them off to a second site.

Comment: I agree.  The fact that the Programmer site exists implies that "softer" topics are at least welcome on StackExchange sites.  If those topics are welcome, the question boils down to whether softer topics dilute the technical side of SQA.  With so little traffic, dilution is not a concern.

Answer (score 3):

See also [new post on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/how-to-flag-off-topic-to-migrate-to-sqa)

Part of the problem is the overlap between the sites... in many respects, SQA.SE appears to me to be a subset of P.SE - Probably the only way this could/would be resolved is if P.SE agreed that SQA&T questions were to be considered *off-topic* and hence migrated, and I can't see that happening